# SQL Server - Retrieve last record for each table in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for the last record entered in each table of the database.  I know how to return the last record for each table one at a time.  However, I need to loop through all the tables (about 10,000) and find the last record posted.  I can do this by scripting (i.e. get all tables into an array and then doing a for each).

Is there a way other than getting the last post from a table query and use a system table? For example, I can use "`SELECT name FROM Sys.tables`" to get all the table names, put that into an array, and then a foreach loop to get the last message "`SELECT TOP 1 date FROM table_A ORDER BY date DESC`".

I am hoping there is a field in a system table that holds when tables were last updated.  I prefer not to script a for each query, I would rather run a SQL query.  I have not found such.

This is what I can do (not actual syntax) but I want to use SQL query without querying the table - is this possible?

```
Array = "SELECT name Sys.tables"
foreach item in Array execute "SELECT TOP 1 date FROM item ORDER BY date DESC"
```

Comment: Does every table of your database have a [date] column?. Its different to know when a table was last updated that to identify the last record of it

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed.aspx

Comment: What is your *overall* goal? Is this auditing? Something else? Describe the larger problem, and let people suggest solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **sp_MSforeachtable** stored procedure to execute a query on all tables in a database.

For example, `exec sp_MSforeachtable 'select top 1 * from ?'`

Comment: `ORDER BY` your `IDENTITY` type column (id, row_id, etc. any column that has unique values stored in it) or a `current date` column descending. So the query should be something like `exec sp_MSforeachtable select top 1 * from mytable order by id desceding`.

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in way to well when a table was last updated: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/.

Beware that this is not reliable if you restart SQL Server. The DMV is cleared out, so it may look like a table has never been accessed when in fact it may have been accessed 5 minutes before the restart. Aaron Bertrand added a comment on this fact and blogged about it here:

- [When was my database / table last accessed?](https://sqlblog.org/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed)

Alternatively, if you need a transactionally consistent answer, you can loop through all table names and issue a query for all of them. It seems to be a feasible way to do this.

Comment: -1 "There is no built-in way to well when a table was last updated"  That's an incorrect statement.  A quick google search says it is: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/  Please clarify if I misunderstood.

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this via SQL is to create a view or make it easier for someone to run an ad-hoc query via SQL mgmt studio.  Also, I would prefer not to run queries against db that uses an application that is prone to table locks (I cannot do anything about the app - it is what it is).  In fact, I grab record counts using the sys.tables because I do not want to do "SELECT count (*) FROM Table with NO LOCk" for fear of locking to taking the app offline.  Yes, this happens with queries like this, like I said, the app is what it is.

Comment: @白ジェームス, thanks! I did not know that. I edited my answer (and turned it around completely).

Comment: The blog helped! I can now run a query against the sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats table and see the last time stamp of a table.  I take it I just have to make sure all my indexed are setup and running.  This is what I am looking for as I do not care what the last record states, I just want to know when.

Comment: Beware that this is not reliable if you restart SQL Server. The DMV is cleared out, so it may look like a table has never been accessed when in fact it may have been accessed 5 minutes before the restart. I blogged about this here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed.aspx

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I will take that advise.  I see that in my UAT database.  When I figure my final query I will post it here.

Comment: @usr please include some salient info from the article (at least the table name `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`) otherwise your post may be flagged as "not an answer" and converted into a comment. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I do not want to take Aarons credits. I think that by providing multiple links and additional thoughts it is justified have such a post. It is clearly useful.

Comment: FYI.. I never figured out my query.  Hopefully the info that is here is enough for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Change Data Capture or have LastUpdate type columns to be able to get this data reliably.

Any kind of query on the primary key won't work as primary keys are ordered in ascending or descending order for that data type and not based on the time the record was inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I have a ugly way to do what you want (If you want your result in a single query sp_MSforeachtable would not work)  ... it seam to take forever to do on my database because the date is not indexed but it should work.

```
DECLARE @Req AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Req = (SELECT LEFT(ids,LEN(ids) - 6) 
           FROM
           (SELECT 'SELECT (SELECT Top 1 date FROM ' + t.name + ' ORDER BY date DESC) UNION ' 
            FROM Sys.tables t 
            INNER JOIN Sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                AND c.name = 'date'
            WHERE t.schema_id = 1
            FOR XML PATH('')) a(ids)
           WHERE ids IS NOT NULL
             AND LEN(ids) > 7)
EXEC(@Req)
```

Comment: That is assuming that you have a column named date used as a last update date in all your relevant tables of your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "Select * from table";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con); // con is connection 

ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

int last = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);

string id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[last-1]["State"].ToString();

textBox1.Text = id;
```